# AlertDialog botão para confirmar ERROR

Tags: java, android

Meus amigos estou com um problema, busquei entender o funcionamento do AlertDialog, onde o foco era criar dois botôes para confirmar o dialogo. O código que estou utilizando é este:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by turkojanownz on 06/07/16.
 */
public class Manager{

    public static void Enviar(Context context, EditText[] Text, String opcao) {
        if (Manager.CheckEditText(Text) == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Preencha os campos, nome, telefone com DDD e a mensagem para enviar a mesma.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (Manager.CheckEditText(Text) == 1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Informe o DDD e o telefone, para continuar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (Confirm(context)){
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String Telefone = "12997040012";
            String Mensagem = opcao + Text[0].getText().toString() + "\nRemetente: " + Text[1].getText().toString() + "\n" + Text[2].getText().toString();

            ArrayList<String> smsEmPartes = smsManager.divideMessage(Mensagem);

            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(Telefone, null, smsEmPartes, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Mensagem enviada com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean Confirm(Context context) {
        final boolean[] retorno = new boolean[1];
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Deseja realmente enviar a mensagem?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int arg) {
                retorno[0] = true;
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int arg) {
                retorno[0] = false;
            }
        });
        dialog.setTitle("Confirmação");
        dialog.show();
        return retorno[0];
    }

    public static short CheckEditText(EditText[] Campos){
        for (int i = 0; i<Campos.length; ++i){
            if (Campos[i].getText().length() == 0){
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (Campos[2].length() < 10) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 2;
    }
}
```

E quando executo esta função obtenho a seguinte exceção:

`07-06 17:36:58.545 8484-8484/louvaiaosenhorjesus.teste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: louvaiaosenhorjesus.teste, PID: 8484
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:953)
            at louvaiaosenhorjesus.teste.Manager.Confirm(Manager.java:58)
            at louvaiaosenhorjesus.teste.Manager.Enviar(Manager.java:29)
            at louvaiaosenhorjesus.teste.MainClick$1.onClick(MainClick.java:33)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)`

[image: Error]

O que eu desejo fazer é que exiba um dialogo quando o usuario clicar no botão enviar, este dialogo fará uma pergunta simples para o usuario se ele deseja confirmar a ação. Se souber uma forma para criar esse dialogo e que ele funcione eu agradeço.

Comment: Qual é o context que você está passando para sua função `Confirm(Context context)`?

Comment: getBaseContext()

Comment: Tente passar a `Activity` como context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar um tema pelo construtor.

Exemplo:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialog);
```

Comment: É isso ai, muito obrigado meu amigo que Deus lhe abençoe!

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme.**

Verifique o tema que está utilizando na activity. Como dito no erro você precisa utilizar um AppCompatTheme.

Comment: Alterei o tema no manifest mas continua a levantar a exceção